# Wordpress / 960 grid issue with IE

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, 960.gs

I'm having a problem with the styling of my website in Internet explorer,

the website looks perfect in Chrome, Safari, Firefox (windows/apple) but IE won't get the css correctly,

**pictures are in the comment below**

http://rikvandoorn.nl/waldorf

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please elaborate on "won't get the css correctly". In what way does IE not display the page correctly?

Comment: Also, you might consider adding the "internet-explorer" tag to help users find your question.

Comment: Images: 
Chrome:  correct css
http://i.stack.imgur.com/DMCbG.png

IE:  
http://i.stack.imgur.com/fY1n2.jpg

Comment: there is an ie only css you may need to work on it

Comment: problem is already solved.. the IE only css had a width of 960px with this set on 100% it was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is already solved.. the IE only css had a width of 960px with this set on 100% it was solved